# How to make advanced audit changes in 2008 (non-R2)?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-event-log

I am trying to configure auditing settings across my domain.  My domain controllers are Windows Server 2008 and the rest of my environment is either 2008 or 2008 R2.  Some of the audit policies I need to set are settings that appear in the Advanced Audit Policy settings in Group Policy...which only apears on Server 2008 R2.

Since my domain controllers are 2008 (non-R2), how do I make these more granular audit settings instead of the general ones offered by the basic audit policies in group policy and make them propagate across my domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Microsoft's [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff182311(v=ws.10).aspx) suggests, Advanced Audit Policy configuration through GPO only works for Windows 2008 R2 and above.

On Windows 2008 you must use [`auditpol.exe`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731451.aspx) to set configure each setting (or *subcategory*) manually.

If you still want to centralise management of the audit configuration through Group Policy you can include the `auditpol` commands in Logon and Startup scripts